# Separability vs. Resolution - Synonymous terms?

Tags: quantization, measurement, resolution, separability

In terms of discrete representation of a variable, let's say time measurements in absolute values in [seconds], is there a difference between separability and resolution? When do speak of either aspect? Or **are those terms used synonymously?**

> *Example*: Measuring arrival time of two physically distinct flights
>   landing, are there examplary different contexts, in which we would
>   distinguish between time separability of flight arrival times and time
>   resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Most technical terms, such as these two, do not get their definitions purely from their **etymology**, but rather from the context of application, by experience and by tradition of acceptance.

And for this case, your understanding of **separability** as the allowence (or ability) of someone to *distinguish between two closest time of arrivals* seems a synonym to the more classical term **resolution** in your context. Nevertheless, they will (and can) take their absolute precise definitions only when they are given mathematical expressions to be quantified...

Note that, in multi-dimensional signal processing, the term separability assumes a completely different meaning too, and which is not related to the discussion here...

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate on separability in the context of multi-dimensional Signal processing? Or refer to a source with an intuitive explanation on this, if possible?